# Django - Multiple data values in fusion pie charts

Tags: django, django-models, fusioncharts

I want to add multiple data values in my pie charts taking model fields. currently i am doing this:

```
 def detail(request, pk):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
else:
    bowler = Bowlers.objects.get(pk=pk)
    select_list = UserSelect.objects.filter(user=request.user, bowler=pk)
    all_select = UserSelect.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
    team = Team.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    dataSource = {}
    dataSource['chart'] = {
        "caption": "last year",
        "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
        "xAxisName": "Month",
        "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "theme": "zune",
        "type": "doughnut2d"
    }
    dataSource['data'] = []
    # Iterate through the data in `Revenue` model and insert in to the `dataSource['data']` list.
    data = {}
    data['label'] = bowler.name
    data['value'] = bowler.ave
    dataSource['data'].append(data)
    column2D = FusionCharts("doughnut2d", "ex1", "600", "350", "chart-1", "json", dataSource)
    context = {
        'bowler': bowler,
        'select_list': select_list,
        'all_select': all_select,
        'team': team,
        'output': column2D.render()
    }
    return render(request, 'bowler_detail.html', context)
```

and i want to add more values something like this: (this is JSON format of adding multiple data values)

```
  "data": [
    {
        "label": "Venezuela",
        "value": "290"
    },
    {
        "label": "Saudi",
        "value": "260"
    },
 ]
```

Any guide how will I add more values fetching from django models in my chart?

Comment: What do you mean with "*more values*"?

Comment: How would you render these extra values in the *same* pie chart? As labels?

Comment: just like the sample i posted label1 value1, label2 value2

Comment: But this generates the correct data, right? Are you looking to *improve* the readability of the code, or change something *functionally*?

Comment: apologies for the unclear question, now i have edited the part, i want to get different field values according to id in one chart

Comment: right now i am just getting one field value 'ave' in my pie chart and i am willing to add more like 'sr' 'runs' etc

Comment: Refer this post for details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067828/django-fusion-charts-to-display-all-values-in-one-pie-chart/52139337#52139337

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for pie chart -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Include the `fusioncharts.py` file which has required functions to embed the charts in html page
from ..fusioncharts import FusionCharts

# Loading Data from a Static JSON String
# It is a example to show a Pie 3D chart where data is passed as JSON string format.
# The `chart` method is defined to load chart data from an JSON string.

def chart(request):
    # Create an object for the pie3d chart using the FusionCharts class constructor
  pie3d = FusionCharts("pie3d", "ex2" , "100%", "400", "chart-1", "json", 
        # The data is passed as a string in the `dataSource` as parameter.
    """{ 
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Recommended Portfolio Split",
            "subCaption" : "For a net-worth of $1M",
            "showValues":"1",
            "showPercentInTooltip" : "0",
            "numberPrefix" : "$",
            "enableMultiSlicing":"1",
            "theme": "candy"
        },
        "data": [{
            "label": "Equity",
            "value": "300000"
        }, {
            "label": "Debt",
            "value": "230000"
        }, {
            "label": "Bullion",
            "value": "180000"
        }, {
            "label": "Real-estate",
            "value": "270000"
        }, {
            "label": "Insurance",
            "value": "20000"
        }]
    }""")
  
    # returning complete JavaScript and HTML code, which is used to generate chart in the browsers. 
  return  render(request, 'index.html', {'output' : pie3d.render(), 'chartTitle': 'Pie 3D Chart'})
```

Also refer Slice Data Plot using API - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/slice-data-plot-using-custom-api-in-django