# Django - Fusion Charts to display all values in one pie chart

Tags: python, django, fusioncharts

This is the relevant Fusion charts code for a pie chart. I want to display all the attributes in my database of all entries but according to 'name'

```
  dataSource2['data'] = []
    # Iterate through the data in `Revenue` model and insert in to the 
 `dataSource['data']` list.
    for key in all_books:
        data = {}
        data['label'] = key.name
        data['value'] = key.price
        dataSource2['data'].append(data)
```

Elaboration: Following concept i want to achieve to display all single parameters for every entry

```
    data[value1]=key.printingcost
    data[value2]=key.papercost
    data[value3]=key.binding
```

Is it possible(in pie charts) suing Fusion charts library??

Attached picture for reference
[image: Reference image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for rendering pie3d chart inn FusionCharts you need to create a data array, which would contain label and value as each object, you can showcase many data in the pie chart, but pie charts are not ideal for showcasing large data, but FusionCharts will draw the pie slices accordingly with your data, to know more about pie charts check this link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts#pie-d-chart-2

FusionCharts also provides a dedicated Django wrapper, using which you could fetch the data from the database and render the chart accordingly - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/install-using-django

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The data for the chart should be in an array where each element of the array is a JSON object, and having the `label` and `value` as key value pair.

You can refer the document to fetch the data from database - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/create-charts-in-django-using-database

Sample code for pie chart -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Include the `fusioncharts.py` file which has required functions to embed the charts in html page
from ..fusioncharts import FusionCharts

# Loading Data from a Static JSON String
# It is a example to show a Pie 3D chart where data is passed as JSON string format.
# The `chart` method is defined to load chart data from an JSON string.

def chart(request):
    # Create an object for the pie3d chart using the FusionCharts class constructor
  pie3d = FusionCharts("pie3d", "ex2" , "100%", "400", "chart-1", "json", 
        # The data is passed as a string in the `dataSource` as parameter.
    """{ 
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Recommended Portfolio Split",
            "subCaption" : "For a net-worth of $1M",
            "showValues":"1",
            "showPercentInTooltip" : "0",
            "numberPrefix" : "$",
            "enableMultiSlicing":"1",
            "theme": "candy"
        },
        "data": [{
            "label": "Equity",
            "value": "300000"
        }, {
            "label": "Debt",
            "value": "230000"
        }, {
            "label": "Bullion",
            "value": "180000"
        }, {
            "label": "Real-estate",
            "value": "270000"
        }, {
            "label": "Insurance",
            "value": "20000"
        }]
    }""")
  
    # returning complete JavaScript and HTML code, which is used to generate chart in the browsers. 
  return  render(request, 'index.html', {'output' : pie3d.render(), 'chartTitle': 'Pie 3D Chart'})
```

Also refer Slice Data Plot using API  - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/slice-data-plot-using-custom-api-in-django